# Pressing Tab is not leaving the TextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a custom control inheriting from `TextBox`. I added the following code to it:

```
public enum TextType : byte
{
    AlphaNumeric = 0,
    Numeric,
    Currency,
}

protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);

    if (this.textType == TextType.Numeric)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }

    else if (this.textType == TextType.Currency)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != ',';
    }
}
```

When typing, the above code executes correctly. However, I have a strange problem:

When I enter the control and simply press Tab (the control is still empty), the cursor moves to the next control. But when I enter some text, clear the text and press Tab, the cursor does not move to the next control.

I don't believe that the above code is the problem. What else can it be?

**EDIT**

The problem occurs when the control is bound to a datasource. When the control is unbound, the above behavior doesn't occur.

Is this normal and is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you try to insert a data type than can not be stored in the datasource. Ex : UI value = "test"(which is string) , datasource type = int.

Answer (score 0):

It may be validation failing, are you handling any Validating events by any chance ?

Or the keypress may be trapped higher up, does the code break in your OnKeyPress when you press the tab key in your test scenario ?

Comment: I'm not handling Validation events and the code doesn't break in OnKeyPress when pressing Tab. It breaks on all other keys. Could it be because the control is bound to a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve the problem:

1. Set each control `CausesValidation` property to `false`

or

2. Set the form's `AutoValidate` property to `EnableAllowFocusChange`